# Bibliography article : how to replace the long line by the author name in the references

Tags: bibliographies, article

I'm using `\documentclass{article}`.  I'm also using `bibliographystyle{ecta}`. My references are in a separate bibtex file.

After generating the PDF file,  when I have two different citations from the same author, in the second citation a long line is drawn instead of the author's name.

Please let me know How to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please compose a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? This basically means stripping down your file to the minimal content that reproduces the error. You can put in a sample `.bib` file with the package `filecontents`. P.S.: You can highlight code by indenting it 4 spaces, pressing the `{}` button, or, for inline use, enclose it in ``

Answer (score 1):

This is correct (assuming that `ecta.bst` correctly implements the relevant style): it's also common: bibliographies often replace the same name with dashes, and many styles require it.

If you really don't want it, but otherwise want the ECTA style, then make a copy of `ecta.bst` and put it in your working directory (or somewhere TeX will find it), renaming it `myecta.bst`. Search through it for the following lines:

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname := s }
     { s oldname =
%         { "---" }   old style
         { "---\hspace{-.1pt}---\hspace{-.1pt}---" }    
%SPD 2000
         { s 'oldname := s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

Delete (or comment out) those lines, and replace them with

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash} {}
```

This will prevent the behaviour you are seeing. But, before doing that, be sure that it's really what you need. (Obviously you will need to use `\bibliographystyle{myecta}` in place of `ecta`.)

(Please don't modify the file without copying and renaming it!)