# authors being left out in one bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, kile

In the bibliography, I have an entry whose authors names get replaced by a long dash whenever I change the style from `plain` to `savetrees`:

```
\bibliographystyle{savetrees}
\bibliography{all}
```

Here is an excerpt from my **.bib** file. The entry whose authors don't get displayed is the second one. But whenever I slightly modify the names, everything works.

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/infocom/WeinsbergSM11,
  author    = {Udi Weinsberg and
               Augustin Soule and
               Laurent Massouli{\'e}},
  title     = {Inferring traffic shaping and policy parameters using end
               host measurements},
  booktitle = {INFOCOM},
  year      = {2011},
  pages     = {151-155},
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/INFCOM.2011.5934941},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/infocom/2011},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
@inproceedings{Kanuparthy:2011:SED:2068816.2068860,
 author = {Partha Kanuparthy and Constantine Dovrolis},
 title = {ShaperProbe: end-to-end detection of ISP traffic shaping using active methods},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGCOMM conference on Internet measurement conference},
 series = {IMC '11},
 year = {2011},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1013-0},
 location = {Berlin, Germany},
 pages = {473--482},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2068816.2068860},
 doi = {10.1145/2068816.2068860},
 acmid = {2068860},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {active probing, inference, traffic shaping},
}  
@inproceedings{soule2004flow,
  title={Flow classification by histograms: or how to go on safari in the internet},
  author={Augustin Soule and Kav{\'e} Salamatia and Nina Taft and Richard Emilion and Konstantina Papagiannaki},
  booktitle={ACM SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review},
  volume={32},
  number={1},
  pages={49--60},
  year={2004},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

Here's an excerpt from the corresponding **.bbl** file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname selectlanguage\endcsname\relax
  \def\selectlanguage#1{\relax}\fi

\bibitem{Kanuparthy:2010:DDI:1833515.1833745}
P.~Kanuparthy and C.~Dovrolis.
\newblock Diffprobe: detecting isp service discrimination.
\newblock In \emph{Proceedings of the 29th conference on Information
  communications}, INFOCOM'10, pp. 1649--1657. IEEE Press, Piscataway, NJ, USA,
  2010.
\newblock ISBN 978-1-4244-5836-3.

\bibitem{Kanuparthy:2011:SED:2068816.2068860}
---.
\newblock Shaperprobe: end-to-end detection of isp traffic shaping using active
  methods.
\newblock In \emph{Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGCOMM conference on Internet
  measurement conference}, IMC '11, pp. 473--482. ACM, New York, NY, USA, 2011.
\newblock ISBN 978-1-4503-1013-0.

\bibitem{soule2004flow}
A.~Soule, K.~Salamatia, et~al.
\newblock Flow classification by histograms: or how to go on safari in the
  internet.
\newblock In \emph{ACM SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review}, vol.~32, pp.
  49--60. ACM, 2004.
\end{thebibliography}
```

How should I interpret this? I have no clue as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `savetrees` package isn't doing anything out of the ordinary -- a quotation dash in a bibliography is standard notation for indicating that the author(s) of that paper is identical to those of the preceding entry. We see from comparing your .bib and .bbl excerpts that Kanuparthy:2010 and 2011 have matching authors.

If you want to revert this behavior, see the previous solutions to related questions -- they mostly involve commenting out or deleting the contents of the `name.or.dash` function in the appropriate .bst files, which in your case is lines 864-874 of `savetrees.bst`.

[Bibliography article : how to replace the long line by the author name in the references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75503/bibliography-article-how-to-replace-the-long-line-by-the-author-name-in-the-re)

[Prevent ibid tracking in natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71200/prevent-ibid-tracking-in-natbib)

Comment: Oh ok, if that standard notation, then I'm totally ok with it. I just didn't know. Thank you!